# How to change the thumb of my Slider and the Bar with particular image

Tags: iphone, uislider

In my app i have a slider which i need to customize. I have some pictures which i want to put on bar and thumb of the slider. 
Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look in the documentation? `UISlider` has several methods to change its appearance:

```
setMinimumTrackImage:forState:
setMaximumTrackImage:forState:
setThumbImage:forState:
```

If that's not enough for your needs (e.g. because one image per slider element is not enough), you'll have to subclass `UISlider` and probably draw the slider yourself.